# ASP.NET without Web Api package

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, dnx

I build a web api service for mobile and web, it works fine on azure, but soon I realised that Nuget Manager has NOT installed Web Api package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi".

I know that Core Controller combines MVC and Web Api functions for DNX Core, it can work without web api package. But DNX 4.5.1 also does not contain Web Api package. How will my app work on this platform (DNX 4.5.1)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about this `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 5.2.3` ?

> This package contains everything you need to host ASP.NET Web API on
>   IIS. ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP
>   services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and
>   mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building
>   RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.

Here is the link : [**Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 5.2.3**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6. In this case you don't need Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (for MVC 4) nor Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 2 (for MVC 5)

Answer (score 0):

There is no more separate package for `Web API` in `ASP.NET Core`.

There is new combined package called `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core (6.0.0-rc1-final)`

Everything will work on both `DNX 451` and `DNX CORE`

Comment: DNX 4.5.1 works with .net framework 4.5.1, it does not contain combined controller, that is why it needs web api package. I some confused... Where is my mistake?

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Core 1.0 (mostly known as ASP.NET 5) then no separation exists between the controllers

Comment: When I added Web Api package, it successful added to DNX 4.5.1, but DNX 5.0 says that it does not support it. How DNX 4.5.1 works before without this package? For what DNX 4.5.1? I am sorry if I can't correctly ask the question...